# Error package androidx.recyclerview.widget does not exist import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, androidx

I am having an issue with running my app on Android Studio. This error shows on the Build Output.

`error: package androidx.recyclerview.widget does not exist import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;`

How do I run this successfully? The issue seems to be with imports from the Androidx libraries.

[image: error: package androidx.recyclerview...]

Comment: Did you add the recyclerview library in your build.gradle?

Answer (score 3):

Solved it by declaring the recycler view Gradle dependency in Gradle Scripts>build.gradle.

Within `dependencies {}`, I declared the following dependencies

`implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"`

For control over item selection of both touch and mouse-driven selection

`implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-rc01"`

Source: [Declaring dependencies](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview)